# If a complex sequence $(u_n)$ converges to $L$, show $\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^{n}u_r\right)$ converges to $L$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, solution-verification

Let $(u_n)$ be a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{C}$. I want to show that if $v_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^{n}u_r$ and $v_n=v_n^{'}+v_n^{''}$ where $$v_n'=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r\leq\sqrt{n}}u_r$$ and $$v_n''=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{\sqrt{n}<r\leq n}u_r$$ then $(v_n)$ converges to the same limit as $(u_n)$.

I want to check that my below solution is correct given its setup is a little different than the other solutions to this problem on this website.

If $(u_n)$ is convergent in $\mathbb{C}$, then there exists an $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ for all $\epsilon>0$ such that if $n>N_1,$ then $|u_n-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for some $L\in\mathbb{C}$.
So if we want to show $(v_n)\to L,$ then

\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
|v_n-L| & = |v_n'+v_n''-L| \\
 & \leq |v_n'|+|v_n''-L| \\
& =\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r\leq\sqrt{n}}u_r\right|+\left|\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{\sqrt{n}<r\leq n}u_r\right)-L\right| \\ 
&=\left|\frac{u_1+...+u_{\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor}}{n}\right| +\left|\frac{u_{\lfloor{\sqrt{n}+1}\rfloor}+u_{\lfloor{\sqrt{n}+2}\rfloor}+...+u_n}{n}-L\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{u_1+...+u_{\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor}}{n}\right| +\left|\frac{(u_{\lfloor{\sqrt{n}+1}\rfloor}-L)+(u_{\lfloor{\sqrt{n}+2}\rfloor}-L) +...+(u_n-L)+\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor L}{n} \right|
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now, since $(u_n)$ is convergent, it is bounded. Hence there exists $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|u_n|\leq M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So $u_1+...+u_{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}\leq\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor M$. Similarly, since $(u_n)$ is convergent, there exists an $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>N_1$, then $|u_n-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ so since $\sqrt{n}<n$ $$|u_{\lfloor{\sqrt{n}+2}\rfloor}-L| +...+|u_n-L|<\underbrace{\frac{\epsilon}{2}+...+\frac{\epsilon}{2}}_{n-\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor \text{times}}=\frac{(n-\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)\epsilon}{2}$$

Hence $$\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
|v_n-L| 
 & \leq \left|\frac{u_1+...+u_{\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor}}{n}\right| +\left|\frac{(u_{\lfloor{\sqrt{n}+1}\rfloor}-L)+(u_{\lfloor{\sqrt{n}+2}\rfloor}-L) +...+(u_n-L)+\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor L}{n} \right| \\ 
& \leq \frac{|\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor M|}{n}+\frac{|u_{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor+1}-L|+|u_{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor +2}-L|+...+|u_n-L|+|\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor L|}{n} \\ 
& \leq\frac{|M|+|L|}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{(n-\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor) \epsilon}{2n}\leq\frac{|M|+|L|-\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

From the Archimedean property of real numbers, there exists an $N_2$ such that for all $n>N_2$, we will have $\frac{|M|+|L|-\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Hence if we take $N=\sup\left({N_1,N_2}\right)$ with $n>N$, then $|v_n-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$. Thus, we've shown $(v_n)\to L$.

Is this a correct proof?

Comment: Looks alright to me

Comment: Note that instead of $\sqrt{n}$ you can use any function $f(n)$ such that $f(n)/n \to 0$.